# How to make row wise calculation in a mysql table to get summarize result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following records in a mysql table named nozel_reading

[image]

I want to get a summarized result by making difference of last_reading based on nozel_id and shift_id.

Example

[image]

Comment: How did the `date` change in the result?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle here? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: sorry i have edited the post now date in right format #Ullas

Comment: What's the expected result for shift 3? How many shifts can you have in a day? What to do with the 1st shift in the next day?

Comment: Shift is not fixed, its up-to user how many sifts he wants to create in a day for this we have a separate shift_table that contains shift_name and shit_id

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the latest Shift_id number and calculate the difference between the latest and earliest readings (if the reading #s go up) as a daily summary.  Not sure if you wanted the difference in character format or actually calculated out, but you can convert to characters if needed.

```
select dt, nozel_id, max(shift_id) as shift_id, 
case when max(last_reading) - min(last_reading) = 0 
     then max(last_reading) 
     else max(last_reading) - min(last_reading) 
end as Difference
from nozel_reading
group by dt, nozel_id
```

Comment: If only one record for each `date` and `nozel_id` then the `difference` would be `0`.

Comment: True, added a case statement in case that is a possibility

Comment: suppose more than 2 shifts are there for each date and nozel_id. then??

Comment: Still the same daily summarized results: latest shift number and the difference between the maximum integer value for the reading numbers minus the minimum.  So another assumption is that readings only go up.  If not, then you would need to take the reading number based on Shift IDs.